# Mac terminal no acces to files

Tags: macos, terminal, directory, permission-denied

The terminal of my mac cant acces files in the documents folder. I get the following error:

> zsh: permission denied

In system preferences I have given the terminal full disk acces. And when I go to the documents folder -> get info -> my username has read and write rights.
I have also ran chmod 777 on the folder but nothing seems to work. Does someone know what causes this problem?

Edit: it turns out that I cant acces a single file with te terminal. It looks like my terminal doesn't have the rights it should.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue! Nothing seemed to work so I wanted to reset the terminal. To do that I had te remove the following file:

> ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist

Then I restarted the terminal and now I can acces my files again!